# jQuery How to make a color palette with RGB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

Not sure if the title explains itself, but probably not!

Anyway, I have 50 divs and I would like to set the background color from White to Dark Yellow.
The first div would be white and the last dark yellow.

The RGB value for white is 255, 255, 255
The RGB value for dark Yellow is 227, 151, 4

How could I do that with javascript (jQuery) so iterate through each div and make it gradually get darker?

Here's a screen shot 
[image]
Thanks a lot

Comment: You're going to have to find / create some sort of formula for how each one of the R - G - B needs to decrease and iterate through it.

Comment: The RGB part shouldn't be hard, but you want the gradients and color-choosing effect as in the pic as well?

Comment: I created a loop and i am trying to iterate though the colors but doesnt work

Comment: Post the code of what you have so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var divs = $('div'),
    len = divs.length;

var targ_R = 227,
    targ_G = 151,
    targ_B = 4,

    inc_R = (255 - targ_R) / len,
    inc_G = (255 - targ_G) / len,
    inc_B = (255 - targ_B) / len;

divs.css("backgroundColor", function(i, curr) {
    return "#" + toHex(255 - (i * inc_R)) +
                 toHex(255 - (i * inc_G)) +
                 toHex(255 - (i * inc_B));
});

function toHex(n) {
    var h = (~~n).toString(16);
    if (h.length < 2)
        h = "0" + h;
    return h;
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/RSyCM/

Comment: Last 2 divs are white (check with an outline).

Comment: Just one question, why did you conver them to hex? can't we just keep it as rgb?

Comment: @peduarte: Wasn't sure if jQuery fixed any cross-browser issues for rgb, so I went with hex since I know it has wide support.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BBujc/)

```
var r, g, b;

for (var i = 0, count = $("div").length; i < count; i++) {
    r = 255 - i * 3;
    g = 255 - i * 10;
    b = 255 - i * 25;

    $("div").eq(i).css("background", "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")");
}
```

**UPDATE**

To make the last one `rgb(227, 151, 4)` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BBujc/3/)

Comment: Plus 1 for demo! Nearly worked. But I have 50 divs all together, and now it goes to red. Screen shot here: http://cl.ly/image/0D3T2w1O0y2f

Comment: I dont understand how you are coming up with the multiplication values (3, 10 and 25) or yours, Zoltan. there must be a formula somewhere. The last div needs to have the rgb values of 227, 151, 4

Comment: 3, 10 and 25 - that's just approximate. You can calculate them pretty precise, i.e. for red: `(255 - 227) / 50` - that's your multiplication value

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation of Zoltan Toth's answer using the [pusher.color library](http://surfacecurve.org/libraries/color), in case you want to use a library to handle the parsing and blending.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bcronin/UEHUX/5/)

```
var color0 = pusher.color('white');
var color1 = pusher.color('rgb', 227, 151, 4);

for (var i = 0, count = $("div").length; i < count; i++) {
    var amount = i / (count-1);
    var result = color0.blend(color1, amount);
    $("div").eq(i).css("background", result.html());
}
```

​